# polymer css confused about core-scroll-header-panel

Tags: polymer

I'm using the `core-scroll-header-panel` components, everything is fine until I tried to add a css style to one of the dom element. My code is like follows:

```
<core-scroll-header-panel>
<core-toolbar class="tall">
    <core-icon-button icon="menu"></core-icon-button>
    <div flex></div>
    <core-icon-button icon="search"></core-icon-button>
    <div class="bottom middle">
        this is my content
    </div>
</core-toolbar>
<div content>

</div>
</core-scroll-header-panel>
```

The second div's class middle is my custom class, and I want to make it in the middle of the page, so the class has a style as `margin: 0 auto;`

Unfortunately It doesn't work, the `this is my content` is not in the middle of the page, I check the style sheet in Chrome and I find the

```
::content > * {
     margin: 0px 8px;
}
```

makes my `margin: 0 auto` unaffected, any ideas?

Comment: I've fixed this problem by using `horizontal center-justified layout`, but I still want to know how to fix it in a pure css way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the style from outside then you have to use shadow property of the dom on your main page.Hope this will solve your problem

```
core-toolbar::shadow .middle{
margin: 0 auto
}
```